# Comparing Julia variable to `nothing` using !== or !=

Tags: julia, comparison

In some Julia code when can see conditional expression such as

```
if val !== nothing
    dosomething()
end
```

where `val` is a variable of type `Union{Int,Nothing}`

What is the difference between conditons `val !== nothing` and `val != nothing`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, it is generally advisable to use `isnothing` to compare if something is `nothing`. This particular function is efficient, as it is soley based on types (`@edit isnothing(nothing)`):

```
isnothing(::Any) = false
isnothing(::Nothing) = true
```

(Note that `nothing` is the only instance of the type `Nothing`.)

In regards to your question, the difference between `===` and `==` (and equally `!==` and `!=`) is that the former checks whether two things are *identical* whereas the latter checks for *equality*. To illustrate this difference, consider the following example:

```
julia> 1 == 1.0 # equal
true

julia> 1 === 1.0 # but not identical
false
```

Note that the former one is an integer whereas the latter one is a floating point number.

What does it mean for two things to be identical? We can consult the documentation of the comparison operators (`?===`):

```
help?> ===
search: === == !==

  ===(x,y) -> Bool
  ≡(x,y) -> Bool

  Determine whether x and y are identical, in the sense that no program could distinguish them. First the types
  of x and y are compared. If those are identical, mutable objects are compared by address in memory and
  immutable objects (such as numbers) are compared by contents at the bit level. This function is sometimes
  called "egal". It always returns a Bool value.
```

Sometimes, comparing with `===` is faster than comparing with `==` because the latter might involve a type conversion.

Comment: `===` can also be faster because it's easier for the compiler to reason about it than about `==`. Also currently in some cases `isnothing` will give less efficient code than `=== nothing` in loops. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/27681

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat Is still the case that `===` can be faster than `isnothing`? I see that issue has been closed.

Comment: Indeed the performance difference should be fixed now.